# HTML: Adding to auto height to compensate for footer

Tags: html, css, height

Right now, I have set the height of my container to: `height: auto;` but I want to compensate for my footer (which is 100px tall). Without compensation, the auto height is calculated assuming the footer isn't there, but I want to add 100px to the auto height so the footer doesn't cover my content. Is there any workaround or way to do this?

Comment: You need to post some code so we can understand the specifics, such as is the footer contained inside the container, or a sibling? What other CSS is on the page? etc

Comment: Try looking at [Sticky Footer](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/)

Comment: @Alex The footer is outside of the container and is simply a div that is 100px in height. There is not much else to it.

Comment: height: auto will simply make the container as high as it needs to be, depending on its inner contents. Is this what you are going for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
height: calc(100% + 100px)
```

Comment: Does 100% achieve the same thing as auto? I am getting different results with 100%.

Comment: My mistake. Why not just do padding-bottom: 100px?

Comment: Oh I can't believe I never thought of that Haha. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Happens to everyone

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the html and body are set to 100% and also be sure to add vendor prefixes for calc, so -moz-calc, -webkit-calc.

Following CSS works For all browsers

```
height: -moz-calc(100% + 100px);   
height: -webkit-calc(100% + 100px);
height: calc(100% + 100px);
```